Installing PGVector
I tried following the instructions here:
https://github.com/pgvector/pgvector#windows

The error message that I am getting is this:

ERROR:  extension "vector" has no installation script nor update path
for version "0.8.0" SQL state: 22023

Any suggestions? I am not sure what to do, has anyone else experienced this before?
